# Neo4j with APOC: running large CREATE in chunks using apoc.perodic.commit

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Using Neo4j 3.3.4 (portable via the **neo4j console** command), I'm trying to create relationships between "Device" and "Location" nodes based on properties of both. A device has one "OwnedByLocation" property; a location can have up to 14 separate name properties. It's straightforward, but the trouble is that I have about 8,000 locations and 3.5 million devices, so a standard query runs out of memory despite my 24GB heap size.

I did some searching and found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277766/neo4j-long-lasting-query-to-be-split-executed-in-smaller-chunks), and installed the APOC plugin so I could split the query into chunks using periodic.commit. The command I tried is below, but whenever I run it, the browser will disconnect from the database after a couple of minutes, and won't reconnect. I can't tell whether Neo4j is still running or not, but no relationships seem to be getting formed (and there definitely should be matches).

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
match (loc:Location)
WHERE NOT (loc)-[:OwnsDevice]->(:dev)
WITH loc LIMIT {limit}
MATCH (dev:Device)
WHERE dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name1
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name2 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name3 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name4 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name5 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name6 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name7 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name8 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name9 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name10 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name11 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name12 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name13 
OR dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name14
CREATE (loc)-[r:OwnsDevice {Source:'Legacy Database'}]->(dev)
RETURN count(*)
",{limit:10000})
```

Does anyone have any suggestions (using apoc.period.commit or otherwise) for a better way to do this? Short of paying Amazon Web Services $1500 for a supercomputer rental, I'm out of ideas. Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the bug mentioned by @stdob--, you have a few additional major issues.

You only have 8K locations but your periodic commit is using a limit of 10K, so it is not doing anything for you (except slowing you down even a bit more). So, if you tried using a lower limit (say, 1K or even 500), you *might* make some progress -- but it will still be slow.

Your query raises several red flags that indicate you would get much better performance by changing your data model. Right now, you are not able to leverage the power of indexes and relationships to find the devices. Those are the most powerful tools available in neo4j.

For instance, your `MATCH (dev:Device) WHERE dev.OwnedByLocation contains loc.Name1 ...` clauses force neo4j to scan through all 3.5 million devices *per location*. (Not to mention that for each device you are using the `CONTAINS` test 14 times. Is `CONTAINS` necessary, or can you use the less expensive equality test? Also, can the names for a location be stored in an array, and are there always exactly 14 names?)

Here is how I would have designed your data model (assuming that we can use the equality test for names):

```
(:Location {id: 123})-[:HAS_NAME]->(:LocName {name: 'Foo'})

(:Device {id: 765, ownedByLocName: 'Foo'})
```

I would also have created this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Device(ownedByLocName);
```

And here is a new query to create all the `OWNS_DEVICE` relationships:

```
MATCH (loc:Location)
WHERE NOT (loc)-[:OWNS_DEVICE]->()
WITH loc LIMIT {limit}
MATCH (loc)-[:HAS_NAME]->(ln:LocName)
MATCH (dev:Device)
WHERE dev.ownedByLocName = ln.name
CREATE (loc)-[:OWNS_DEVICE {source:'Legacy Database'}]->(dev)
RETURN count(*)
```

The above query only needs to do a quick (indexed) lookup to find all the devices that match each location name.

Comment: Excellent info in both replies, thank you very much. As you can tell, I'm relatively new to the graph database structures. Now's the time to make modeling changes, so I will apply that lesson to our data model altogether to ensure I can leverage indexing.

There is actually a reason for the CONTAINS -- often the local values for the location will be something like "Reno field office", where the Location node's name property will just be "Reno". This happens often enough that it's easier to correct for false positives from CONTAINS than it is to use "=" and miss all of these.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think the problem is that there is a mistake in the query - you are looking at a pattern where there is no connection with the node with the label `:dev`, but you create a connection with the node labeled `:Device`, so the query never ends, because it constantly returns a number greater than zero:

```
WHERE NOT (loc)-[:OwnsDevice]->(:dev)
...
MATCH (dev:Device)
...
CREATE (loc)-[r:OwnsDevice {Source:'Legacy Database'}]->(dev)
RETURN count(*) // Always greater than zero
```

2) You can make the query more compact:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit("
  MATCH (loc:Location)
  WHERE NOT (loc)-[:OwnsDevice]->(:Device)
  WITH loc LIMIT {limit}
  MATCH (dev:Device)
  WHERE ANY(propName IN KEYS(loc) WHERE propName IN {propNames} AND 
                                        dev.OwnedByLocation CONTAINS loc[propName]
        ) 
  MERGE (loc)-[r:OwnsDevice {Source:'Legacy Database'}]->(dev)
  RETURN count(*)
", {limit:10000,
    propNames: ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7", "Name8", "Name9", "Name10", "Name11", "Name12", "Name13", "Name14",
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I should have figured I could pass in the prop names as arguments. If I'd had time to read the documentation properly before trying to put APOC to practical use, I would have picked up on that, but that's a dream for another day. Thanks very much, this was extremely instructive!